# Network Manager stops during 20.04 to 22.04 distro upgrade

Tags: upgrade, network-manager

Network manager stops during upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 and terminal commands don't seem to be working. Plugging into ethernet does nothing either since no network manager.

Going into settings shows:

Oops, something has gone wrong. Please contact your software vendor.
NetworkManager needs to be running.

Currently the installation is nearly finished with installing upgrades and attempting to download corefonts.

What can I do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up restarting my machine and received the error:

```
Kernal Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

I also could not use safe mode via the grub menu and received the same error.

I fixed the issue my using a 22.04 live disk and mounting my linux and efi drives. I then chrooted and used dpkg on the filesystem.

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt install -f
```

After rebooting and removing the live usb my OS loaded perfectly. There may have been a more simple way to fix the issue but this worked for me.